# Looking for suggestion to add Text based link (not clickable) to other high ranking sites

Tags: seo, backlinks, sem

I am working on a research with Text based SEO. Let me create a scenario so that you'll understand what I am trying to achieve and hopefully be able to share your idea.

Say I am looking bring traffic to my website (*example.com*) which has a keyword of Manufacturing Textile Manufacturing In China. I don't want people to click on some site with my link and redirected to my site.

However, when people search for Manufacturing Textile in China, it will show results with multiple sites which has the `{keyword-text} - ({website}) - {optional text}` as their title, either on their search pages or other pages with short description. See the screenshot just for the example.

[image: Shortlink Example]

I have heard people using term Shortlink for this technique, but wanted to know more about how this is done.